# ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure()

Tags: python, django

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
I'm new to django, writing a blog for myself. I have created a blog app, written on models.py.
Here my code:`enter code here`

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body= models.TextField()
    date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: No enough information on your question. I believe your project is not accessing settings.py I think you did not configured your environmental variable properly.